# microsoft facebook sdk

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook

Microsoft recently announced their Facebook SDK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee388574.aspx

Has anyone tried using it with ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC ?

Would like your opinion.  Any gotchas that developers need to be aware of ?

Michael

Comment: +1 for the question.  I'd like to see some live examples of ASP.NET-powered Facebook apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is version 3.0 of the SDK. I've been using an earlier version and am in the process of upgrading to this new version.

Your question is very vague. What kind of gotchas are you expecting? There are so many pieces of the Facebook API that it's hard to speak to what your experience will be. What's stopping you from giving it a try yourself? You'd probably learn more from a few hours of building your own app with the SDK than anything anyone would be able to tell you here. If you get stuck or something doesn't work, then post your code and/or specific question and we'll do what we can to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC app using this library.

I have not used a whole lot of the functionality of the library since there are only two MVC specific class. An Controller Extension for getting a facebook api object, and an Action decorator attribute.

I have run into quite a bit of trouble with the methods in the Facebook.Rest.Data namespace.

Namely getting and setting Cookies.

Not sure what the deal is with this but it has been frustrating. And if it was not required by the client I would probably try and find a different library.